# How do I integrate $\int x\sqrt{A^2 - x^2} \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

$$ \int x\sqrt{A^2 - x^2} \mathrm dx $$

I never dealt with 2 variables on integration, what should I do here?

Comment: You should treat $A$ as a constant. It simply should not interfere with the integration more than any number.

Comment: For the integration itself, think about the formula $[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Comment: I haven't learned that yet. Is there any fundamental way to approach this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ is not a variable here (you can tell the variable of integration is $x$, by the cue $dx$.)

$$ \int x\sqrt{A^2 - x^2} \mathrm dx = \int x(A^2 - x^2)^{1/2} \,dx$$

Let $\,u = A^2 - x^2.\;$ Then $\,du = -2x dx \implies -\dfrac 12 du = x\,dx$.

Now substitute: $$\int -\dfrac 12 u^{1/2} \,du = -\frac 12 \cdot \frac 23(u)^{3/2} + C$$

Now back substitute and simplify: $$-\frac 13 (A^2 - x^2)^{3/2} + C = -\frac 13(A^2 - x^2) \sqrt{A^2 -x^2} + C$$

Comment: Do you see where the -1/2 comes from? $\,du = -2x\,dx \implies -

Comment: I can ignored the A^2 ? Wouldn't I be getting 2A -2X from the chain rule ?

Comment: Yes, since it stands for a number, any number, and when finding du/dx for substitution purposes the derivative of a constant is 0. We just need to keep it when we resubstitute $u = A^2 - x^2$.

Comment: I See. Thank you for the helping again.

Comment: You're very welcome, helpty. that's what we're here for!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int x(a^2-x^2)^{1/2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int(-2xdx)\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}+C=$$

$$-\frac{1}{3}(a^2-x^2)\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+C$$

Comment: I don't see how the -1/2 comes from, could you elaborate

Comment: @helpty Actually, I think it should be $-2x$ in the integral.  If $u=a^2-x^2$, then $du=-2xdx$. Note that $x=-\frac12\times-2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way is using the trigonometric substitution $x=A\sin{t}.$
Then $$dx=A\cos{t}\;dt,\\
{A^2 - x^2}=A^2-A^2{\sin^2{t}}=A^2{\cos^2{t}},$$ therefore
$$\int x\sqrt{A^2 - x^2}\;  dx = \int {A\sin{t}\,A{\cos{t}}}A\cos{t}\;dt =\\
= -A^3 \int {\cos^2{t}\;d(\cos{t})}=-\frac{A^3}{3}\cos^3{t}+C=  -\frac{A^3}{3} \left(1-\sin^2{t} \right)^{\tfrac{3}{2}}+C =\\
=-\frac{A^3}{3}\left({1-\frac{x^2}{A^2}}\right)^{\tfrac{3}{2}}+C=-\frac{1}{3}\left({A^2-{x^2}}\right)^{\tfrac{3}{2}}+C.$$